# Android Notification sound is not working when changing the audio from radiogroup

Tags: android, notifications

I want to give the user a list of sound options to set the sound on notifications. Once the user selects the audio first time, it will play in the notification.
But when the user changes the mp3 second-time notification use old sound to display.
Somewhere I read that once the notification channel is created, It will not be created again until the app is uninstalled and installed again.

Comment: Share the code where your change the music file and set it on the notification